# Big-O for using a for loop to insert into an AVL

Tags: c, algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I was writing a code sample for a company I applied for, and they asked that my code run in **O(n)** in the worst case. I decided to use an AVL tree, but to insert the values I was being given into the AVL tree I had to use a nested loop structure. Does that make my code run in **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** in the worst case or does it run in **O(n log n)**?

EDIT: here is a link to the code on my github: https://github.com/hsleiman1/Algorithms/blob/master/equilibriumIndexAVL.c

My code:

```
int equilibriumIndex(int A[], int N) {
    int i, newRoot = 1;

    while (newRoot < N) {
        node *leftTree = NULL;
        node *rightTree = NULL;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (i == newRoot) continue;
            if (i < newRoot) leftTree = insert(leftTree, A[i]);
            if (i >= newRoot) rightTree = insert(rightTree, A[i]);
        }

        if (addSubTree(leftTree) == addSubTree(rightTree)) return newRoot;
        free(leftTree);
        free(rightTree);
        newRoot++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int addSubTree(node *subTree) {
     if (subTree == NULL)
         return 0;
     else
         return (subTree->value * subTree->repeat) + addSubTree(subTree->left) + addSubTree(subTree->right);
 }

 node *leafInit(node *leaf, int key) {
     leaf = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
     if (leaf != NULL) {
         leaf->value = key;
         leaf->left = NULL;
         leaf->right = NULL;
         leaf->repeat = 1;
     }
     return leaf;
 }

 node *insert(node *leaf, int key) {
     if (leaf == NULL) 
         leaf = leafInit(leaf, key);
     else if (key < leaf->value)
         leaf->left = insert(leaf->left, key);
     else
     if (key > leaf->value)
         leaf->right = insert(leaf->right, key);
     else
         leaf->repeat++;

     leaf = rotate(leaf, key);

     return leaf;
}

node *rotate(node *subTree, int key) {
     node *temp;
     int balance = getBalance(subTree);
     if (balance < -1) {
         temp = subTree->left;
         if (key > temp->value) {
             subTree->left = rightRotate(subTree->left);
             subTree = leftRotate(subTree);
         }
     } else
     if (balance > 1) {
         temp = subTree->right;
         if (key < temp->value) {
             subTree->right = leftRotate(subTree->right);
             subTree = rightRotate(subTree);
        }
     } else
     if (balance < -1 && key < subTree->value)
         subTree = leftRotate(subTree);
     else
     if (balance > 1 && key > subTree->value)
         subTree = rightRotate(subTree);

     return subTree;
 }

 node *leftRotate(node *leaf) {
     node *x = leaf->left;
     node *y = x->right;

     x->right = leaf;
     leaf->left = y;

     return x;
 }

 node *rightRotate(node *leaf) {
     node *x = leaf->right;
     node *y = x->left;

     x->left = leaf;
     leaf->right = y;

     return x;
 }

 int height(node *leaf) {
     if (leaf == NULL) return 0;
     else return max(height(leaf->left), height(leaf->right)) + 1;
 }
 int max(int num, int num1) {
     if (num < num1) return num1;
     else return num;
 }
 int getBalance(node *leaf) {
     return height(leaf->right) - height(leaf->left);
 }
```

Comment: Please add all of the methods that you used to properly diagnose the complexity of the code and tag the question with the language this code is written in to get more attention to it

Comment: Also, it sounds like the company wanted a plain binary tree or a linked list, not an AVL, which is self-balancing and always has O(logn) insertion

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions for the post. I edited the tags, and I'll add the rest of the methods now.

Comment: Also, I used an AVL tree so that addition of both sub-trees would happen in O(log n) time

Comment: Gotcha. I think youre missing the rotate method

Comment: There! Its all there now

Comment: I see rightRotate, where is the method called by `leaf = rotate(leaf, key);`?

Comment: Sorry, its there now

Comment: Thank you. Well, from a quick look, I can tell you that you're code is greater than O(n) and possibly greater than O(n logn) because you call height at every single node, which recursively goes down both sides of the tree

Comment: @cricket_007 would you have any suggestions to make it more efficient?

Comment: My first recommendation would be to actually use the height stored as part of the struct instead of using the recursive method to find the max of the left and the right children. It's been a while since I've done C (or AVL trees), but that's the first inefficiency I can see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an AVL tree will never get you an **O(n)** complexity. If you do it right, which can be tricky, you will get **O(n.log(n))**, and if you miss, you may get a degenerate tree and a complexity of **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

For an **O(n)** complexity, they are expecting you to use a hash table.

Comment: I was under the impression that using a tree would get me O(log n) time. I was using this as a reference: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: @Hossam: each insertion runs in **O(log N)**, but inserting N elements runs in **O(N.log N)** at best.  Can you be more precise regarding what is expected from your code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't for business ethics purposes.